# Required script that used to work suddenly returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a functioning NodeJS program that I used to host on my machine. That program requires other scripts that I made for utilitarian purposes, and was using them properly, but now I am dumbfounded as the same script suddenly returns undefined.
I'm not sure why such a thing is happening, I haven't touched a thing since the program was live on my machine. I guess some snippets are in order.

```
const FileSystem = require('fs')
const credentials = require('../auth/api.json')
const Utils = require('../utils/Utils.js')

let Database = () => { return JSON.parse(FileSystem.readFileSync('./database.json').toString()) }
let Config = () => { return JSON.parse(FileSystem.readFileSync('./utils/config.json').toString()) }
const _pnw = new PnW(credentials.key, credentials.pass)

function parseAlliance(id) {
    _pnw.alliance(id)
        .then(alliance => {
            Utils.log(`Performing checks on ${alliance.members} ${alliance.name} members.`, Utils.LogTypes.CHECK)
            let _alliance_members = alliance.member_id_list
            let _player = _alliance_members.shift()

            parsePlayers(_player, _alliance_members)
        })
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

This specific snippet is specifically importing a `Utils.js` file, which contains lots of useful methods I need for this script to function. However, when I `console.log(Utils)` now, I only get an empty object `{}`.

I know the path to the `Utils.js` file is correct, and I know that it is properly exporting it's methods and properties. I have attempted recloning my project, and rebooting my machine just in case it was a weird quirk of my RAM, but to no avail.
This is quite an important program, I'd like to have it working again soon...

Cheers in advance for the replies

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.
I'm still not sure why, but this specific script cannot import anything from outside its own folder. It used to be able to. It used to work flawlessly. Moving the `Utils.js` folder into the same directory as this script made it work again.

Of course, this isn't a perfect solution, but it works for now. If you have pointers to why this behaviour happened, I'm interested in hearing them.